# State monad: How to `print` intermediate value in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm new in haskell and I have following code

```
module StateTest where

import Control.Monad.State.Lazy

tick :: State Int Int
tick = do n <- get
          put (n+1)
          return n

plusOne :: Int -> Int
plusOne = execState tick

main = print $ plusOne 1
```

And I want to print state value after `put (n+1)` and continue computation like this

```
tick = do n <- get
          put (n+1)
          print
          return n
```

How whole code will look following to this?

Comment: If you want to print some value for debugging-only reasons, have a look at `Debug.Trace.trace`, or the GHCi debugger. This should however not be used of anything else, as it cheats the type system -- the general solution is the one in the answer below by Lee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run IO actions within a state computation you can change the type of `tick` to return a `StateT Int IO Int` and use `liftIO`. Then you can run it using `execStateT`:

```
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

tick :: StateT Int IO Int
tick = do n <- get
          put (n+1)
          liftIO $ print (n+1)
          return n

plusOne :: Int -> IO Int
plusOne = execStateT tick

main = plusOne 1 >> pure ()
```

Comment: ok, and what if I want `tick :: IO (State Int Int)`? how code will look after this?

Comment: @bjornmelgaard - I don't think you can implement it with that type - an `IO a` allows externally visible effects, and a `State s a` is a pure stateful computation. An `IO (State Int Int)` therefore allows you to execute some effects before returning a pure stateful computation, but you want to interleave state changes with effects. Combining features of different monads is what monad transformers like `StateT` are for.

Comment: @bjornmelgaard It's not that difficult. For comparison `IO (Int -> Bool)` is the type of an action which can perform arbitrary I/O, and then returns a pure function which does not do any I/O. Hence, this can never print the integer: the I/O is over before the integer is passed. Instead, `Int -> IO Bool` takes the integer first, then performs I/O, and finally returns a boolean. Here the integer can be printed. This is more or less what's happening under the state-transformer layer (which is indeed a bit tricky to understand at first -- a good monad tutorial should help).

Answer (score 0):

Another option, since you would have to use `IO` anyway to print a value in the intermediate state, would be to use `IORef`. It's a container that has an updateable value.

```
module Main where

import Data.IORef

tick :: IORef Int -> IO (IORef Int)
tick ref = do
  modifyIORef' ref (+1)
  -- you can also print here since it is IO
  pure ref

main :: IO ()
main = do
  counter <- newIORef 0

  tick counter
  v2 <- readIORef counter
  print v2

  tick counter
  v2 <- readIORef counter
  print v2
```

You can then clean it up with `ReaderT`.

```
module Main where

import Data.IORef
import Control.Monad.Reader

readerTick :: ReaderT (IORef Int) IO ()
readerTick = do
  ref <- ask
  -- can also print here with liftIO $ print ...
  liftIO $ modifyIORef' ref (+1)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  counter <- newIORef 0

  runReaderT readerTick counter
  v1 <- readIORef counter
  print v1

  runReaderT readerTick counter
  v2 <- readIORef counter
  print v2
```